# On Shephard-Todd theorem

Tags: reference-request, invariant-theory, reflection-groups

There is an excellent Torsten Ekedahl's answer to Roman Fedorov's question here: [Chevalley–Shephard–Todd theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32450/chevalley-shephard-todd-theorem). Does anyone know any articles or books where this approach is outlined?

I didn't find anything by myself despite the fact that I've looked in a lot of sources...

Comment: The answer you quote mentions such a reference (Bourbaki), have you checked?