# Analogues of worldly cardinals for (an unusual version of) second-order $\mathsf{ZFC}$

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals, higher-order-logics

Let $\mathfrak{ZFC}(\mathsf{SOL})$ be the theory in second-order logic (with the standard semantics) gotten from $\mathsf{ZFC}$ by modifying the Separation and Replacement schemes to apply to arbitrary second-order formulas. For example, for each second-order formula $\varphi$ with only first-order free variables $x_1,...,x_n,x_{n+1}$ we have the Separation instance $$\forall x_1,...,x_n,y\exists z\forall w(w\in z\leftrightarrow w\in y\wedge \varphi(x_1,...,x_n,w)).$$

Note that $\mathfrak{ZFC}(\mathsf{SOL})$ is **not the same as the system called "second-order $\mathsf{ZFC}$"** - see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3064566/what-features-of-a-logic-make-possible-the-proof-of-downward-lowenheim-skolem/3530773#3530773).

Building off of [this MSE question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3550364/28111), I'm interested in understanding the models of this theory. I'm hoping that by restricting to levels of the cumulative hierarchy we can get a clean answer:

> **Question 1**: For which cardinals $\alpha$ do we have $V_\alpha\models\mathfrak{ZFC}(\mathsf{SOL})$?

It's easy to show that every (strongly) inaccessible cardinal has this property; the converse, however, is not immediately clear to me. My current suspicion in fact is that (very) large cardinals imply the existence of non-inaccessible $\alpha$s with the above property, but I don't immediately see how to prove this.

---

As a secondary question, I'm also interested in a "Henkin version" of this question:

> **Question 2**: For which $\alpha$ is there an $X\subseteq \mathcal{P}(V_\alpha)$ such that $(V_\alpha,X)$ forms a Henkin model of $\mathfrak{ZFC}(\mathsf{SOL})$?

At a glance I think that the least such $\alpha$ has countable cofinality, by a quick modification of the analogous argument for worldly cardinals, but I haven't had time yet to check the details.

Comment: Consistently the answer to question 1 is "exactly the inaccessibles". This is Theorem 8.5 in Inner Models from Extended Logics (Part 1), 2020: assuming $V=L$, then the models of ZFC(SOL) are exactly those isomorphic to models of ZFC of the form $L_\kappa$ where $\kappa$ is inaccessible.

Comment: @JasonZeshengChen Woah, I was not familiar with that paper ([link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2007.10764.pdf)) - top of my reading list! Please post this as an answer so I can upvote it.

Comment: Done. I also like this line of work very much. There's also an earlier and shorter [draft](https://www.newton.ac.uk/files/preprints/ni16006.pdf) in 2016 before it was split into a two-parter.

Comment: Is $\mathfrak{ZFC}(\mathsf{SOL})$ the same with $\mathsf{ZFC^{def}}$ in [your another previous question on MSE?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3550364/53976)

Comment: @HanulJeon Yup, as you pointed out in your comment to my other question linked above!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Complementing @JasonChen's answer: Assume ZFC+$I_1$ and let $j:V_{\lambda+1}\to V_{\lambda+1}$ be elementary, so $\lambda$ is the sup of the critical sequence of $j$. Then $V_{\lambda}$ models $\mathfrak{ZFC}(\mathsf{SOL})$, but $\mathrm{cof}(\lambda)=\omega$. For suppose $f:V_\alpha\to\lambda$ is cofinal and definable over $V_{\lambda+1}$ from the parameter $p\in V_{\lambda}$. Let $n<\omega$ be such that $\alpha,p\in V_{\mathrm{crit}(j_n)}$
(where $j_n=$ the $n$th iterate of $j$). Note that $j_n\circ f\neq f$, because taking $x\in V_\alpha$ with $f(x)>\mathrm{crit}(j_n)$, we get $j_n(f(x))>f(x)$. But $j_n\circ f=f$ because $j_n:V_{\lambda+1}\to V_{\lambda+1}$ is elementary and $j_n(p,\alpha)=(p,\alpha)$.

Edit, considering @AsafKaragila's comment on consistency strength: Consistency-wise, the assumption above was overkill; a measurable suffices. Assume ZFC + $\kappa$ is measurable. Let $G$ be Prikry generic at $\kappa$. So $\kappa$ has cofinality $\omega$ in $V[G]$. Claim: In $V[G]$, $V_\kappa$ models $\mathfrak{ZFC}(\mathsf{SOL})$. In fact, if $f:\omega\to\kappa$ is cofinal and $f$ is definable  over $V_{\kappa+1}^{V[G]}$ from parameters in $V_\kappa$, then $f\in V$, so $f$ is bounded. Since $V_\kappa^{V[G]}=V_\kappa^V$, this is a consequence of the fact that $\mathrm{HOD}^{V[G]}_V=V$, i.e. if $X\in V[G]$ and $X\subseteq V$ and $X$ is definable over $V[G]$ from parameters in $V$, then $X\in V$. (This follows from the fact that if $p,q$ are Prikry conditions then there are generics $G_p,G_q$ with $p\in G_p$ and $q\in G_q$ and $V[G_p]=V[G_q]$.)

Edit 2: On the other hand, the kind of argument used in the paper "Inner models from extended logics: Part 1" referred to in @JasonChen's answer to show that in $L$,  $V_\alpha$ models $\mathfrak{ZFC}(\mathsf{SOL})$ iff $\alpha$ is inaccessible, also works for the standard fine structural $L[\mathbb{E}]$ models $M$ for short extenders, for instance if $M$ has no largest cardinal, and assuming $M$ has Mitchell-Steel indexing, though I expect it would also work with Jensen indexing. So if those models are indeed consistent through ZFC + superstrongs, then one would need more than ZFC + ``There is a superstrong extender'' to prove there is a non-inaccessible $\alpha$ with $V_\alpha$ modelling $\mathfrak{ZFC}(\mathsf{SOL})$.

(The paper "The definability of the extender sequence $\mathbb{E}$ from $\mathbb{E}\upharpoonright\aleph_1$ in $L[\mathbb{E}]$" contains enough to generalize the argument of Kennedy, Magidor, Väänänen for $L$. The definability there is all done over $\mathcal{H}_\kappa$s, as it's more convenient, but that can be translated into the cumulative hierarchy with the usual coding; in the present case that's only actually needed at the very top, since we can assume $V_\alpha\models\mathrm{ZFC}$ to start with.)

Edit 3: Following @AsafKaragila's suggestions in the comments, we have:

Claim: Suppose $V_\lambda$ models $\mathfrak{ZFC}(\mathsf{SOL})$ but $\lambda$ is singular. Then for every $X\in V_\lambda$,  $X^\#$ exists. Moreover, there is a proper class inner model $M$ with a measurable cardinal.

Proof: For simplicity take $X=\emptyset$. Suppose first that $0^\#$ does not exist. Note first that since $V_\lambda$ models ZFC, $\lambda$ is a (singular) strong limit cardinal. By Jensen's covering lemma, $\lambda$ is singular in $L$. Let $B$ be the constructibly least singularization. Then $B$ can be defined over $V_{\lambda+1}$ (without parameters), which contradicts $\mathfrak{ZFC}(\mathsf{SOL})$.

The argument for an inner model $M$ with a measurable is likewise, but using the Dodd-Jensen core model: We also have the appropriate version of covering for that core model $K=K^{\mathrm{DJ}}$, and $K|(\lambda^+)^K$ can also be defined in the codes over $V_{\lambda+1}$, and hence the least singularization of $\lambda$ in the $K$-order is definable.

So Edits 1 and 3 together give that  ZFC + "There is a singular $\lambda$ such that $V_\lambda\models\mathfrak{ZFC}(\mathsf{SOL})$" is equiconsistent with ZFC + "There is a measurable cardinal".

Comment: Interesting. Can we prove that if there is a singular cardinal satisfying this axiom then something like $0^\#$ exists, or maybe even more? (core model coverings galore)

Comment: Nice point about the Prikry sequence... What about the sharps? Measurable cardinals tend to come with some sharps.

Comment: Also to simplify your claim about HOD and whatnot, it's just homogeneity (of its Boolean completion). Indeed, that's exactly what your last sentence is proving.

Comment: Very nice! Just checking: the above still does not establish that "There is a non-inaccessible $\alpha$ with $V_\alpha\models\mathfrak{ZFC}(\mathsf{SOL})$" has large cardinal strength, right?

Comment: That's right...

Comment: @AsafKaragila, right, I don't know if it gives $0^\sharp$...@NoahSchweber actually it does imply $\alpha$ is inaccessible in $L$, by the argument for $L$. But I don't know if it gives anything beyond an inaccessible.

Comment: I guess it's enough to argue that if $\alpha$ has this certain property, then it has it in $L$ (by arguing that it is regular there, anyway). This would imply that a singular one is regular in $L$, so $0^\#$ must exist. And probably we can argue that $\alpha$ is a sharp cardinal (i.e. every set in $V_\alpha$ has a sharp) or something like that (if my idea holds water).

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right, so it does give $X^\sharp$ for every $X\in V_\alpha$.

Comment: (As I mentioned above, the proof of Kennedy, Magidor, Väänänen shows $\alpha$ is inaccessible in $L$. And it relativizes to $L[X]$ for $X\in V_\alpha$. So your argument goes through.)

Comment: Great, so now we just need to show the other direction: if $\alpha$ is sharp, then it satisfies this version of ZFC(SOL).

Comment: What do you mean "this version"?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the one in the question (which isn't $\sf ZFC_2$).

Comment: (Also, I'll record my joy that the notion of "sharp cardinals" turns up here so naturally. Very nice!)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Actually, as you suggested in the first place, your argument extends to show that if for some singular $\alpha$, $V_\alpha$ models ZFC(SOL), then there is an inner model with a measurable. So the consistency strength is exactly a measurable cardinal. (Use the Dodd-Jensen core model below a measurable, for which covering in the sense of $L$ also holds. It's also easily definable, so one can argue like for $L$.)

Comment: We can use this as an example for https://mathoverflow.net/questions/385732/proofs-of-theorems-that-proved-more-or-deeper-results-than-what-was-first-suppos :P

Comment: @AsafKaragila It'd be good if the sharps etc is recorded in another answer. Do you want to put one with it? Otherwise I can incorporate it above.

Comment: You probably can write it better. I'm no authority when it comes to sharps.

Answer (score 8):

As discussed in the comment, Theorem 8.5 in the paper [Inner Models from Extended Logics: Part 1](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.10764) by Kennedy, Magidor, and Väänänen gives a consistent answer that, assuming $V=L$, models of $\mathfrak{ZFC}(\mathsf{SOL})$ are exactly those isomorphic to models of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ of the form $L_\kappa$ where $\kappa$ is inaccessible.

Comment: I can only accept one answer and I've gone with Farmer's, but thank you very much for this citation!

Comment: @NoahSchweber This is interesting since inaccessibles $\kappa$ are precisely the cardinals such that $V_{\kappa+1}\models MK$. If a similar result holds for models of MK assuming $V=L$ then (assuming $V=L$) models of MK and $\mathfrak{ZFC}({\sf SOL})$ coincide exactly.