# Papers whose title defines a new terminology

Tags: reference-request, big-list, soft-question

To explain a new signal processing technique based on Fourier Transform, Bogert et al went on to define a new vocabulary. The new terminology was published in a paper with the title:

**The Quefrency Alanysis of Time Series for Echoes: Cepstrum, Pseudo-autocovariance, Cross-Cepstrum, and Saphe Cracking**, B.P. Bogert, M.J.R. Healy, J.W. Tukey, Proc. Symp. Time Series Analysis, M. Rosemblatt, Ed., John Wiley & Sons, 1963, pp. 209-243.

**Spell-checkers are not recommended...** :-)

**ADDED:** As we can see, the authors changed the position of the letters in the paper title to reflect the phenomenon analysed (echo in communication). Then, they used these new words to nominate the signal processing technique.

> The question is: are there another papers with this characteristic (papers where the unusual terminology in the title reflect the phenomenon analysed) ?

Only the term *Cepstrum* has been widely used.

BTW, [Cepstrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cepstrum) is the result of taking the Inverse Fourier transform (FT) of the logarithm of the spectrum of a signal. There is a complex cepstrum, a real cepstrum, a power cepstrum, and phase cepstrum. The power cepstrum in particular finds applications in the analysis of human speech.

**ADDED:** *The **idea** of the kepstrum appears in the classical work of Poisson (1823), Schwarz (1872), Szego (1915), and Kolmogorov (1939), and has been applied to geophysical problems by Robinson (1954), Bogert et al. (1963), Schafer (1969), Oppenheim and Schafer (1975), Tribolet (1977), and others.*, M.T. Silvia, E.A. Robinson, **Use of *Kepstrum* in Signal Analysis**, Geoexploration, 16, 1978, pp. 55-73.

*Our word “kepstrum” means the same as their term “complex cepstrum”. Because the kepstrum of a real-time sequence is real, the use of the word “kepstrum” is less confusing than the term “complex cepstrum”.*, M.T. Silvia, E.A. Robinson, **Use of *Kepstrum* in Signal Analysis**, Geoexploration, 16, 1978, pp. 55-73.

Comment: Mlibey        .

Comment: I feel this is a subquestion to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/22299/what-are-some-examples-of-colorful-language-in-serious-mathematics-papers-clos and should be closed.

Comment: @Gubkin, thank you for your comments. IMHO, this is not a subquestion because there is no colorful language in this paper. The authors changed the position of the letters in the paper title to reflect the phenomenon analysed (echo in communication). This defines a whole vocabulary that they used to nominate the new signal processing technique.

Comment: Ah I see.  So you are only interested in papers where the unusual terminology became widely accepted.  By "this characteristic" I thought you meant just that the title was unusual.

Comment: What counts as unusual terminology that has became widely accepted?  For example, Sylvester introduced tons of unusual words into mathematics (totient, syzygy, etc.).  Do those count, or are you just looking for word play like "cepstrum"?

Comment: @Cohn, please, see "ADDED". Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Ossters (Bogert et al).

Comment: @David I do not believe in a large list of answers because the context is very restrictive. But... 

Comment: @PaPiro: if you do not believe/want a list of answers, why did you tag it big-list in the first place?! In addition, the only way in which this question IMO can make any sense is if it is intended as collecting (all/many) such examples. As opposed to looking for an answer 'Yes, there are other such examples; this one other example "proves" this.'  

Comment: @quid: I do not believe... but I want a very big huge list of answers. If so, CW. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: @PaPiro: if I understand correctly, you are after papers with *neologisms* (not just "unusual words") in the title. What extra conditions you want these neologisms to satisfy isn't quite as clear, but mathematicians create language all the time. By restricting the scope enough you should be able to concoct a valid question on that general subject.

Comment: I like Grothendiecks Dessins d'enfants

Comment: @Francois: The neologisms in the title should reflect the phenomenon analysed. Quefrency, e.g., is frequency changed by the echo effect in communication. Cepstrum is spectrum, and so on. The phenomenon analysed was used to creates its own new terminology. There is no joke, no colorful language. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: This cacophonous concoction evidently entailed tongues stubbornly stuck in cheeks, an achievement probably unrepeatable, of dubious distinction. So says he who opted for an opus entitled "A hyperbolic-by-hyperbolic hyperbolic group".

Comment: Could you kindly stop the endless editing of this question. If you want to get it reopened and/or improved start a discussion on meta (you'd need to signup there too, but this is trivial and instant)

Comment: I'm reminded of the title essay of Mermin's *Boojums all the way through: communicating science in a prosaic age* (admittedly his original boojum article was not a math paper, though the collection does include a short mathematical exposition or two).  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boojum_(superfluidity) .

Comment: @quid I am sorry if I make you feel uncomfortable. Thank you very much for your information about meta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jean-Pierre Serre: [Gèbres](http://ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1225256), *Enseign. Math.* (2) **39** (1993), 33–85.

Answer (score 2):

Diener, Francine; Diener, Marc
[Chasse au canard. I. Les canards.](http://ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0643399) (French) [Duck hunt. I. The ducks] 
Collect. Math. 32 (1981), no. 1, 37–74.

Benoît, Éric
[Chasse au canard. II. Tunnels—entonnoirs—peignes.](http://ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0653888) (French) [Duck hunt. II. Tunnels—funnels—combs] 
Collect. Math. 32 (1981), no. 2, 77–97.

Callot, Jean-Louis
[Chasse au canard. III. Les canards ont la vie brève.](http://ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0653889) (French) [Duck hunt. III. Ducks have a short life] 
Collect. Math. 32 (1981), no. 2, 99–114.

Benoît, Éric; Callot, Jean-Louis
[Chasse au canard. IV. Annexe numérique.](http://ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0653890) (French) [Duck hunt. IV. Numerical appendix] 
Collect. Math. 32 (1981), no. 2, 115–119.