# Special Lagrangians and fat

Tags: reference-request, sg.symplectic-geometry, mirror-symmetry, calabi-yau, lagrangian-submanifolds

I am unable to find the MO comments about the first use of the phrase "fat slags" in an article. [On page 26 of this](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0104196) we find "these correspond to thickenings of the
corresponding special Lagrangian (giving fat SLags, as they are known in Britain,
or multiply-wrapped cycles in physics speak)."

As this arXiv paper is 2001, the whole business long precedes the beginning of MO in any case; what I remember is at least one comment expressing astonishment that the authors who invented the term fat SLags actually were able to put it in a real mathematics/physics paper without screams from a referee.

Anyway, this may be going into a survey talk for amateurs. Something juicy, you see.

Comment: I don't see a choice for CW; maybe that is one's own choice for answers only.

Comment: Next time you want to make a question CW, Will, just flag it for moderator attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer and its comments, is the reference you are searching for:
https://mathoverflow.net/a/22384/2051

The paper in which the term appears appears is http://arxiv.org/abs/math.DG/0104196

Comment: So the arXiv preprint I mention is the place the phrase was invented, and R.P. Thomas is himself the comedian. Good to know.