# History of use of "=" symbol to mean "is canonically isomorphic to"

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ho.history-overview

Let $A$ be a commutative ring, and let $f$ and $g$ denote elements of $A$ such that the prime ideals of $A$ containing $f$ are precisely the prime ideals containing $g$ (a not completely trivial example of this phenomenon would be $f=r^2$ and $g=r^3$ for some element $r\in A$). If $D(x)$ denotes the set of prime ideals of $A$ which don't contain $x$, then we hence have $D(f)=D(g)$.

If $M$ is now an $A$-module, then Grothendieck in EGA1 (on his way to defining a sheaf of modules on an affine scheme) would like to associate an abelian group to the set $D(f)$, and he chooses the localisation $M_f=M[1/f]$. He'd also like to associate an abelian group to the set $D(g)$, and he chooses $M_g$. The thing is that $D(f)$ and $D(g)$ are equal, and from a strict set-theoretic point of view $M_f$ and $M_g$ are not (at least according to Grothendieck's definition of localisation in EGA0, and assuming the standard set-theoretic model of the quotient by an equivalence relation as a set of subsets). However Grothendieck argues that this doesn't matter, arguing that both $M_f$ and $M_g$ are canonically isomorphic to the localisation of $M$ at the multiplicative subset of $A$ consisting of elements which don't vanish on $D(f)=D(g)$, or in other words at the saturation of both the ideal $(f)$ and $(g)$, and hence are canonically isomorphic to each other. As we can see in the below screenshot from EGA1, Grothendieck uses the notation $M_f=M_g$
to denote this canonical identification.
[image: a quote from EGA1]

This idea of using the symbol $=$ to mean something more delicate than the standard ZFC usage of "having the same elements" is prevalent in algebraic geometry, and history indicates that it rarely if ever causes any problems. For example in Milne's book on etale cohomology, written in 1980, we see the following in "Terminology and conventions" on page xiii:

[image: milne's etale cohomology book]

so one would imagine that by 1980 this convention had become standard. My question is whether the convention of using $=$ to denote a canonical isomorphism was due to Grothendieck in 1960 in EGA or whether anyone knows of a historical precedent. For example are there earlier works in homological algebra which use this kind of convention? According to [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/22360) Weil was talking (rather sarcastically!) about the concept of a canonical map in 1959, which makes me wonder about whether this use of $=$ was already prevalent in some of the literature.

Just to make sure that the conversation doesn't get derailed: I know that in some other foundations of mathematics (for example in univalent type theory) one really can construct a term of type $M_f=M_g$; however this is not relevant to my question, because these univalent ideas came historically much later, and Grothendieck was using set-theoretic foundations anyway. I am well aware that under some simplifying hypotheses (for example if $A$ is an integral domain) one could argue that $A_f$ and $A_g$ are equal as subsets of the field of fractions of $A$, but at this point in EGA1 it is essential that we do not work under these simplifying assumptions. Finally, I am also not particularly interested about whether it is a good idea to use $=$ to mean more than one thing; my interest here is purely historical.

Comment: My dim recollection from my youth was that there was not at all any settled convention on this. I think in the 1960s the set-theoretic influence made it hard to set a good context to communicate things like "unique up to unique isomorphism". People were cavalier about writing equality for isomorphism, and so on. But I do not know about Grothendieck's specific contribution...

Comment: Before TeX, it was difficult to type (and print) math symbols, so, for example, people (e.g., Grothendieck) would use "=" for "canonical isomorphism". If the isomorphism is really canonical, or there is a given isomorphism, this causes no problems. This was certainly widespread in certain circles in the 60s and 70s.

Comment: It had never occurred to me that typesetting issues were a possible reason for this choice of notation! In the EGA screenshot there is \in and \subset though, although I guess these were probably written in by hand in the version handed to Publ Math IHES...

Comment: You've seen me write about this elsewhere, but I'm now writing it up properly. We can track the use of "canonical" for mappings in archived Bourbaki drafts to at least 1938. And by the late 40s it seemed relatively common among some of the collaborators of Bourbaki to use the adjective canonical, and not sarcastically like in the Weil joke you link. BTW Grothendieck was already using = for canonical isomorphisms  in his 1952 _Résumé des résultats ..._ (i.e. his thesis summary, published in Annales Inst. Fourier https://doi.org/10.5802/aif.46)